# How to resize and transform labels?

Tags: ios, view, label, transform, frame

My application requires the user to enter few details which are then displayed via another view by using labels.

As the user can enter variable length of text, while the label initially had a fixed length and breadth,  I used a code like the following to adjust the label size:

```
    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(296,9999);
         CGSize expectedLabelSize = [yourString sizeWithFont:yourLabel.font 
                                    constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize 
                                    lineBreakMode:yourLabel.lineBreakMode]; 

            //adjust the label the the new height.  
CGRect newFrame = yourLabel.frame;  
newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;  
yourLabel.frame = newFrame;
```

The problem with these modifications is that I have many labels one after the other. So when I change the length of one label, all the following labels also need to be transformed/moved to new locations.

Is there any way that I can change the size and location of all labels dynamically, while ensuring that the final presentation is as good as it was in case of fixed length labels?

Comment: You need to manage all the label's height dynamically. Like take an int variable 'h' give the initial value as like 'yourLabel.frame.size.origin.y'... after that h = h + expectedLabelSize.height...give this h value to the next label's y position

Answer (score 0):

```
 int h=10; // Initial Height as you want
        for(int k=0;k<[headItemArray count];k++) {
            CGSize size_txt_overview1 = [[headItemArray objectAtIndex:k] sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
            UILabel *lbl_headitem = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3,h, 690, size_txt_overview1.height)];// See the 'h' value
            lbl_headitem.text = [headItemArray objectAtIndex:k];
            [lbl_headitem setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
            [lbl_headitem setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            [lbl_headitem setTag:k];
            lbl_headitem.numberOfLines=0;  
            [lbl_headitem setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
            [lbl_headitem setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18]];
            [scrollAttributes addSubview:lbl_headitem];
            h = h + size_txt_overview1.height;// important
        }
```